# Function return error in clause having ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Good afternoon!
I have a function where she does the bank reconciliation with a .txt of the bank with the system, where she shows the number of the launch whose value is exactly equal to the one launched in the system, the problem is that there is 1 debit in the .txt that corresponds to ha several launches in the system of the same client id, in .txt I do not have the client id but the sum of the values ​​launched corresponds exactly to the debit, is there any way to do this query? ... I am trying to use the in the variable sum_lancamentos having for me returns the ids but is generating synthase error. and I believe that all this function could be improved, I just don’t know how, I’m a new RoR and I’m still getting used to good practices.
Any help is very life and thank you in advance!

```rb
 def conciliacao
    @conciliacao = session[:conciliacao_file]

    comparacao = {}

    @conciliacao.each do |key, line|
      data = line[:data]
      valor = line[:valor].to_f.round(2)
      if line[:mov] == "D"
        despesa = true
      else
        despesa = false
      end
      lancamentos = Lancamento.ativos.pagos.where(conta_id: params[:conta_id], despesa: despesa).where("lancamentos.data_pagamento BETWEEN '#{data.to_date.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}' AND '#{data.to_date.end_of_day.to_s(:db)}'").where(["cast(lancamentos.valor  AS NUMERIC(15,2) ) = :value or
      cast(lancamentos.valor_pago AS NUMERIC(15,2)) = :value ",
        { value: line[:valor] }])
      unless lancamentos.blank?
        lancamentos.each do |lancamento|
          #puts line
          @conciliacao[key][:lancamentos] = "#{lancamento.id}"
          @conciliacao[key][:status] = 1
          @conciliacao[key][:color] = "green lighten-4"
        end
      else
        sum_lancamentos = Lancamento.ativos.pagos.group(:cliente_id).where(conta_id: params[:conta_id], despesa: despesa).where("lancamentos.data_pagamento BETWEEN '#{data.to_date.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}' AND '#{data.to_date.end_of_day.to_s(:db)}'").having(["sum(cast(lancamentos.valor  AS NUMERIC(15,2) )) = :value or sum(cast(lancamentos.valor_pago AS NUMERIC(15,2))) = :value ", { value: line[:valor] }])
        unless sumlancamentos.blank?
          @conciliacao[key][:lancamentos] = "#{sum_lancamentos.ids}"
          @conciliacao[key][:status] = 1
          @conciliacao[key][:color] = "green lighten-4"
        end

      end
    end
    session.delete(:conciliacao_file)
  end
```